# How to disable Force Click Lookup programmatically?

Tags: cocoa, chromium-embedded

I need to disable Force Click Lookup in my application that uses CEF.

Already tried to override `quickLookWithEvent` in `NSApplication`, `NSWindow` and `NSTextView` without any affect (the method doesn't get called during the event).

Actually I need to achieve the same affect as when unchecking "Force Click and haptic feedback" checkbox in the Preferences, but to do it programmatically. Is there a way to prevent the lookup window from showing on force clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code did the trick:

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults
    setInteger:0
        forKey:@"com.apple.trackpad.forceClick"];
```